# Swift DispatchGroup notify before task finish

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch

I'm using `DispatchGroup` to perform a task, but `group.notify` is being called before the task is completed.

My code:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let queueImage = DispatchQueue(label: "com.image")
let queueVideo = DispatchQueue(label: "com.video")
queueImage.async(group: group) {
    sleep(2)
    print("image")
}

queueVideo.async(group: group) {
    sleep(3)
    print("video")
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("all finished.")
}
```

Logs:

```
all finish.
image
video
```

Comment: Running your code in an Xcode 9.2 playground results in the expected output, not the output shown in your question.

Comment: I tested it in an actual app built with Xcode 9.2 and it also worked just fine there too.

Comment: Make sure you have imported Playground support @rmaddy says it does not have any issues

Comment: When I run the original code in the repl it does sort of work .. except it does not actually print anything. note that the `sleep` 's _are_ working

Comment: Actually .. now it's behaving the opposite: printing is happening but _immediately_ ie the `sleep` is being ignored. this is strange.

Comment: same thing is working fine now in playground.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**  The question above actually runs correctly as is (as rmaddy pointed out!)

I'm saving this wrong answer below in case others get confused about DispatchQueue's async(group:) methods behavior, since [Apple's swift doc on it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016098-async) is currently lousy.

---

The group's enter() needs to be called before each call to async(), and then the group's leave() needs to be called at end of each async() block, but *within* the block.  It's basically like a refcount that when it reaches zero (no enters remaining), then the notify block is called.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
let queueImage = DispatchQueue(label: "com.image")
let queueVideo = DispatchQueue(label: "com.video")

group.enter()
queueImage.async(group: group) {
    sleep(2)
    print("image")
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
queueVideo.async(group: group) {
    sleep(3)
    print("video")
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("all finished.")
}
```

Comment: Then what is the point of the `group` parameter in the calls to `async`? That usage should preclude the need for calls to `enter` and `leave`.

Comment: @rmaddy I couldn't find any docs or examples to support what you said, but I went ahead and tried it (removing the enter and leave lines completely) and it worked.  Will keep looking for docs... curious.  Will withdraw my answer.

Comment: Read the corresponding Objective-C documentation. It has more details.

Comment: I suppose [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) covers it enough to be believable.  Thanks rmaddy!

Comment: @Victor Why did you accept this answer? No offense to Smartcat but this answer isn't correct because the code in your question works as-is. There is no need to use the calls to `enter` and `leave`.

Comment: @rmaddy The update at the top of the answer is correct, and it's the only posted answer, so I guess he was happy enough with it. I, for one, would feel better if you posted your own answer (you figured it out, after all!), and then Victor could re-accept to your answer, as [this meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93970) advises.  Cheers!

Comment: But answers that state "your code works" are not considered acceptable answers on SO. There's nothing to post. The question actually should be closed as an unreproducible issue.

Comment: When I run the *original* code in the `repl` it does sort of work .. except it does not actually print anything. note that the sleep's _are_ working

Comment: @Smartcat I was calling group.enter() inside an async block .sometime it works appropriately and sometimes it runs notify() before even the block start execution ..Thank You for the explanation this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Generic answer : (Swift 5)

```
let yourDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

yourDispatchGroup.enter()
task1FunctionCall {
  yourDispatchGroup.leave() //task 1 complete
}

yourDispatchGroup.enter()
task2FunctionCall {
  yourDispatchGroup.leave() //task 2 complete
}

.. ..
yourDispatchGroup.enter()
tasknFunctionCall {
  yourDispatchGroup.leave() //task n complete
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  //This is invoked when all the tasks in the group is completed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `DispatchGroup` is a `lazy var`, try to not call the `notify` method inside the initialization code block.

```swift
lazy var dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup = {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    // not call here dispatchGroup.notify(...

    return dispatchGroup
}()
```

You need to call all the `enter` methods before the `notify` method:

```
dispatchGroup.enter()

dispatchQueue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
    // ...
    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("all finished.")
}
```